# Printing 2d array box

Tags: c

I am new to programming. Figuring on how can I print out the box using `for` loop so it makes a big box? I had attached the sample below. I really need help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{     
 int a;

 printf("\n --- \n");
 for(a=1;a<=1;++a)
 printf("\n|   |\n");
 printf("\n --- ");

 return 0;
}
```

Example output:

[image: Example output]

Comment: What is your problem with the code you show us? What is the actual output of that program? What output did you expect? Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Looks like some homework. You need to show what effort you have been made and describe your question more specific.

Comment: @some programmer dude sorry for imprecise, what I want is to print out a 2d array box with '---' on top and '|' on the side.

Comment: @RyanHu For your information this is not a homework, it's part of my assignment program.

Comment: @CristyLim You can edit your question to make it reasonable.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more details. Most important is what you want to use it for. And to give you a hint about what you need to do (after looking at the image), you probably need *two* loops, one inside the other.

Comment: Start by writing a for loop that draws a line `------` variably. Your program doesn't even do that, you have written a for loop that only runs 1 time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work. You need basic understanding of nested loops to be able to do this question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int rows, cols, i, j;

    printf("Enter rows for box: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &rows) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid rows\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Enter columns for box: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &cols) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid columns\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("\n2D Array Box:\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
            printf(" --- ");
        }
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
            printf("|   |");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    /* bottom "---" row */
    for (i = 1; i <= cols; i++) {
        printf(" --- ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first character(`' '`) and repeat string (`"--- "`)
first line and repeat contents line and bar line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MARK "X O"

//reduce code    
#define DRAW_H_BAR()\
    do {\
        putchar(' ');\
        for(int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)\
            printf("%s ", h_bar);\
        puts("");\
    }while(0)

void printBoard(int rows, int cols, int board[rows][cols]){
    const char *h_bar = "---";
    const char v_bar = '|';

    DRAW_H_BAR();//first line
    for(int j = 0; j < rows; ++j){
        //contents line
        putchar(v_bar);
        for(int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
            printf(" %c %c", MARK[board[j][i]+1],v_bar);
        puts("");
        DRAW_H_BAR();//bar line
    }
}

int main(void){
    int board[8][8] = {
        {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
        {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1},
        {-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0},
        {0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1}
    };
    int rows = sizeof(board)/sizeof(*board);
    int cols = sizeof(*board)/sizeof(**board);
    printBoard(rows, cols, board);
}
```